# Using GPS in New Apple Watch Series 2 WatchOS 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-watch, watchos

Apple announced the Apple Watch Series 2 recently with a new GPS chip inside. I am wondering if Apple has released the public API for this new hardware. Maybe we are expecting to see something similar to CLLocation. 
Worst case would be that we have to wait until WatchOS 4. Has anyone some idea about using GPS in the new Apple Watch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation).

As far as I'm aware, you can write the same code regardless of whether you're running on a Series 1 or Series 2 device. If you're on a Series 1 (or "series 0" original watch), location services use data forwarded from the paired iOS device's GPS, and on a Series 2 you get data from either the paired iOS device or the watch itself (depending on whether the paired iOS device is with the user or has been left behind), but the switchover is transparent to your app.

Comment: An other question. If my phone is nearby, I'd rather start the tracking there and just report updates to the watch to display it. On a series 2 I'd ask the user where he wants to track? Is there a way to figure out if the watch I am currently running on has a build in gps?

Comment: @Georg You cannot control where the GPS is run, core location uses the iPhone if it can and the watch if not